# Why program is not continuing after the procedure is done(emu8086)?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Hello i wanna make procedure which sum two numbers entered from screen in emu8086, i like the program to continue after the procedure is finished 
i call the procedure sumUp and it does it good but after ret in the procedure the program finishes.. i want the program to continue bellow the code call sumUp 
Thank you very much

```
; multi-segment executable file template.

data segment
   message1 db "Enter 2 number..$"

   num1 db 0
   num2 db 0           
   suma dw 0

ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment   

    sumUp proc

      pop bx
      pop ax 
      sub ax,30h

      mov suma,ax
      pop ax    
      sub ax,30h
      add suma,ax

    ret
    sumUP endp


start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

; add your code here

    lea dx,message1
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

    mov ah,1h
    int 21h

    mov num1,al

    mov ah,1h
    int 21h

    mov num2,al

    mov dh,0d
    mov dl,num1
    push dx

    mov dh,0d
    mov dl,num2
    push dx

    call sumUp      
    //I want the program to continue here after procedure is finished

    **mov cx,0**



ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

Comment: The `ret` instruction doesn't return from procedure. It pops return address from stack and jumps there. You lost it by doing `pop bx` at beginning of `sumUp`, loading the return address into `bx`, and you didn't restore it back, so the `ret` will pop completely different value from stack to jump to. The CPU doesn't understand anything about procedures, the `call/ret` instructions are imitating that by using stack memory, but it works only as long as you keep the structure of stack correct.

Comment: And the more common way how to load arguments in pass-in-stack calling conventions is by having function prologue: `push bp` `mov bp,sp` ... continuing with proc body... `mov ax,[bp+4] ; arg1` `add ax,[bp+6] ; arg2` `sub ax,2*'0'` `mov [suma],ax` and ending with epilogue restoring stack `mov sp,bp ; may be omitted if sp is correct` `pop bp` `ret` .. or to simulate your "args removed by proc" `ret 4` to remove the two arguments (4B) from stack after `ret`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push bx` needs to be added:

```
code segment

    sumUp proc

      pop bx
      pop ax
      sub ax, 30h

      mov suma, ax
      pop ax
      sub ax, 30h
      add suma, ax

      push bx ; needs to be added here
    ret
    sumUP endp
```

Comment: You modify the caller's `sp` by doing that.  Some calling conventions do have the callee pop the args off the stack, but normally that's done with `ret 4` (to do the equivalent of `add sp, 4` after popping the return address).  If your caller isn't expecting your function to do that, it's bad.  Your function is super inefficient, BTW.  You should pop into two different registers instead of storing to `suma`.  Or make a stack frame so you have random access to stack memory.

Answer (score 1):

You're messing up the return address on the stack, so it's not there when `ret` wants to pop it (into `IP`).

Instead of popping to access data on the stack, set up `bp` as a frame pointer so you can access stack memory with it as a base register.

You have to save/restore your caller's `bp`; normally with push/pop, but in this case we can stash it in `cx` (which you don't have to save/restore) because the function is simple and doesn't need multiple temporary registers.

```
 ; multi-segment executable file template.

data segment
   message1 db "Enter 2 number..$"
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment   

    ; inputs: first arg in AX, 2nd arg on the stack
    ; clobbers: CX
    ; returns in: AX
    sumUp proc

      mov cx, bp       ; save caller's BP
      mov bp, sp
      mov ax, ss:[bp+2] ; get the value of pushed parameter without messing with top of the stack          
      mov bp, cx       ; restore it.

      ret  

    sumUP endp

start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

; add your code here

    lea dx,message1
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

    mov ah,1h
    int 21h        

    mov ah, 0
    sub al, 30h

    push ax

    mov ah,1h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 0
    sub al, 30h 
    ; no need to push second operand because its already in ax 
    call sumUp                               

    ; result in ax

    mov ah, 04ch
    int 21h  

ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

Comment: @Peter Cordes How about this code is it optimized ? :D

Comment: Looks pretty horrible.  Make a stack frame the normal way so you can use `ret`  (and don't forget to save the caller's `bp`) .  There's no point using `call` at all if you're going to use `jmp resume`, and mismatched call/ret breaks the return-address predictor stack so you'll get branch mispredicts on some later `ret` instructions after doing this.

Comment: The machine encoding of `[bp]` needs an extra byte for a disp8 = 0, i.e. `[bp+0]` (if 16-bit is the same as 32-bit on this), because there's no encoding for `[bp]` without a displacement.  This makes sense because if you make a stack frame the normal way, `[bp]` points to the saved value of the caller's `bp`, which you don't need to access.  So you can use `[bp+4]` to access the first arg.  (or 2nd if you pass the first in `ax`).  Thus you should `push bp` / `mov bp,sp` / `add ax, [bp+4]` (SS: is implicit for BP) / `pop bp` / `ret`.  (`leave` would work too, but you didn't modify `sp`.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes Check it out i edited it now with `ret`. :D

Comment: You still clobber the caller's `bp` without restoring it.  And also their `bx` for no reason.  IDK much about 16-bit calling conventions, but I think `bx` is normally call-preserved.  Use `cx` or `dx`, or better just `add ax, [bp+2]` (or +4 once you fix the save/restore issue).  The `add bp,2` is still pointless.

Comment: @PeterCordes what about now ?

Comment: I like your idea of using `cx` instead of the stack to preserve the caller's value of `bp`.  It's larger code-size than push/pop (by 1 byte per instruction), but apparently load/store was quite slow on 8086 CPUs so saving that store/reload is probably worth the extra code-fetch.  And it's probably better on a modern CPU in 16-bit mode, too.

Comment: So this is actually good for tiny functions where you need to access a stack arg, but you don't need more than 2 scratch registers.  Of course if you're making up calling conventions (like first arg in `ax` instead of all on the stack), might as well pass multiple args in registers, like `ax`, `dx`, `cx`, so this 2-arg function can be `add ax,dx` / `ret`.  And BTW, loading into `dx` with `mov` instead of using `add ax, ss:[bp+2]` is still an obvious waste of an instruction.  Why are you using that?

Comment: well `add ax, ss:[bp+2]` does not work! it does not add the two values in fact it does nothing.

Comment: It can't "do nothing".  If it loads a `0` from the stack it could leave `ax` unchanged, though.  Did you put it after you'd already restored the caller's `bp` value?  IDK why `2+caller_bp` would be pointing at a zero, but I guess that's the non-existant return address of `start`?
  I'm 100% sure that you're just doing it wrong.

Comment: I had forgot to store the value of `bp` in `cx` and then later assign `bp` back to `cx` now it works.

Comment: When answering questions, don't forget to actually answer it in English.  Code dumps aren't good answers if you don't say which part of a whole program has the relevant change.